# Limit click event to button inside modal when modal open and not to buttons with same class outside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

This is a WooCommerce site: https://www.mediatics-desa.com/desa/mako/shop/

I've added AJAX to add products, and it works fine. But if you click on the image, a modal opens with the description of the product (not very needed but clients want it). There's another button there, but when I click it, it always trigger the add to cart function twice. I assume it's because it gets the info twice because there are to identical buttons... But ''m not sure how to solve it without creating a mess. My JS skills are a little limited.

This is the function (but the whole code is here: https://www.mediatics-desa.com/desa/mako/wp-content/themes/mako/js/main.js?ver=5.0.3):

```
function addCartAjax() {
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass('ajax_add_to_cart');

    $('.mako-producto').on('click', '.quantity .quantity-button', function () {
        return false;
    });

    $('.mako-producto').on('change input', '.quantity .qty', function () {
        var add_to_cart_button = $(this).parents(".mako-producto").find(".add_to_cart_button");
        // For AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.data('quantity', $(this).val());
        // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.attr('href', '?add-to-cart=' + add_to_cart_button.attr('data-product_id') + '&quantity=' + $(this).val());
    });

    $('.input-text.qty.text').bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.product_quantity').val(value)
    });

    $('.mako-producto').on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart', function(e) {
        console.log($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
        var $thisbutton = $(this);
        $('.ajaxerrors').remove();

        if ($thisbutton.is('.ajax_add_to_cart')) {
            $thisbutton.removeClass('added');
            $thisbutton.addClass('loading');
            var product_id = $(this).attr('data-product_id');
            var quantity = $(this).attr('data-quantity');
            var data = {
                action: 'bodycommerce_ajax_add_to_cart_woo_single',
                product_id: product_id,
                quantity: quantity
            }

            $('body').trigger('adding_to_cart', [$thisbutton, data]);
            $.post(wc_cart_fragments_params.ajax_url, data, function (response) {
                if (!response)
                    return;
                var this_page = window.location.toString();
                this_page = this_page.replace('add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart');
                if (response.error && response.product_url) {
                    window.location = response.product_url;
                    return;
                }
                if (wc_cart_fragments_params.cart_redirect_after_add === 'yes') {
                    window.location = wc_cart_fragments_params.cart_url;
                    return;
                } else {
                    $thisbutton.removeClass('loading');
                    var fragments = response.fragments;
                    var cart_hash = response.cart_hash;
                    if (fragments) {
                        $.each(fragments, function (key) {
                            $(key).addClass('updating');
                        });
                    }
                    $('.shop_table.cart, .updating, .cart_totals').fadeTo('400', '0.6').block({
                        message: null,
                        overlayCSS: {
                            opacity: 0.6
                        }
                    });
                    $thisbutton.addClass('added');
                    if (fragments) {
                        $.each(fragments, function (key, value) {
                            $(key).replaceWith(value);
                        });
                    }
                    $('.widget_shopping_cart, .updating').stop(true).css('opacity', '1').unblock();
                    $('.shop_table.cart').load(this_page + ' .shop_table.cart:eq(0) > *', function () {
                        $('.shop_table.cart').stop(true).css('opacity', '1').unblock();
                        $(document.body).trigger('cart_page_refreshed');
                    });
                    $('.cart_totals').load(this_page + ' .cart_totals:eq(0) > *', function () {
                        $('.cart_totals').stop(true).css('opacity', '1').unblock();
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
$(function() {
    addCartAjax();
});
```

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried applying window.event.stopPropagation(); or event.stopPropagation(); in your function call?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't do anything. But now I see that if I close the modal and add another product without changing the quantity, it load the event twice as well. If you open the console you can see the output.

Comment: Not sure if this question is still relevant since this link: https://www.mediatics-desa.com/desa/mako/shop/ does not work